# VSCode Remote SSH to Apple Silicon M1 having a terminal in i386 arch instead of arm64

Tags: visual-studio-code, apple-m1, apple-silicon

Actually developing on an Intel MacBookPro with Visual Studio Code. The project being edited is on an Mac Mini M1 via the Remote-SSH feature.

When connecting through regular SSH to the Mac Mini M1, the `arch` command issues `arm64` as an answer which is what's expected.

The Visual Studio Code terminal connected to the same machine issues `i386` instead. This has some undesired side effects making the currently developed app crash in that context, but not in the regular SSH session.

Is there a way to turn the Visual Studio Code Remote-SSH terminal in `arm64` mode?